# Not able to open sub links except homepage NGINX AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hosting

Not able to open other links except the homepage,

In below code you can see I am trying to host react app on AWS using nginx but it is opening only home page, if click any link it is not opening.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

      

        root /home/ubuntu/frontend/build;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

       }

client_loop: send disconnect: Connection resetpache's document root
```